# DolphinDB Python API: Issues with partitionColName when writing data to dfs table with compo domain

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb

It's my understanding that the PartitionedTableAppender method of DolphinDB Python API can implement concurrent data writes. I'm trying to write data to a dfs table with compo domain where the partitions are determined by the values of "datetime" and "symbol". Now the data I'd like to write include records of 150 symbols in one day. This is what I tried:

[image]

But it seems only one partitioning column can be specified in partitionColName. Please inform me if I do have a wrong way of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify one partitioning column in this case even if it uses compo domain. Based on the given information, it is suggested to specify partitionColName to be "symbol" and then concurrent writes can be implemented. However, the script still works if you set it to be "datetime", but the data cannot be written concurrently because it only contains one day's records with which only one partition is created.

Refer to the basic operating rules when you are using `PartitionedTableAppender`:

1. DolphinDB does not allow multiple writers to write data to one
   partition at the same time. Therefore, when multiple threads are
   writing to the same table concurrently, it is recommended to make sure each of
   them writes to a different partition. Python API provides a
   convenient way by dividing data by partition automatically.
2. With DolphinDB server version 1.30 or above, we can write to DFS
   tables with the PartitionedTableAppender object in Python API. The
   user needs to first specify a connection pool. The system obtains
   the partitioning information before assigning them to the connection pool
   for concurrent writing. A partition can only be written to by one
   connection pool at one time.

Therefore, only one partitioning column is needed for a table with compo domain. Just specify a highly-differentiated partitioning column to create numbers of partitions and assign them to multiple connection pools. Thus, the data can be written concurrently to the dfs tables.